# How to render template tags in the views and send them to Ajax calls

Tags: django, django-templates

In Django i am using bootstrap4 form from the package `django-bootstrap4`

it renderst the form using

```
{% bootstrap_form form %}
```

Now i just need only this part using a view like

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def rendertemplatetag(request)
      form = DeviceForm()
      rendered_template = bootstrap_form(form) <-- something like this
      where renedered_template can be string
      # return as json
      return HttpResponse(rendered_template,status=200,content_type="application/json")
```

I am using DRF for this view

this view can be called with ajax and then the returned html can be substituded at its place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django has a function `render_to_string` which you can use to render a template, and save the rendered HTML (well anything actually) as a string.

#### Solution

Have some template:

```
# some_template.html
{% bootstrap_form form %}
```

```
# views.py
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

@api_view(['GET'])
def rendertemplatetag(request)
    form = DeviceForm()
    rendered_template = render_to_string("some_template.html", {"form": form})
    # return as json
    data={"form":rendered_template}
    return JSONResponse(data)
```

(django also has a `JSONResponse` object to automatically set all the correct headers for you etc.)